# Zeppelin Context not recognized by Windows 10 Local

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I just set up Zeppelin Notebook locally on my machine (Windows 10 OS) and when I go to run it, everything seems to work fine, except for the zeppelin-context methods:

```
val values = List(1,2,3,4,5)
val df = values.toDF()
df.show()
```

The above returns:

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    1|
|    2|
|    3|
|    4|
|    5|
+-----+
```

However, when I run `z.show(df)`, I get the following error:

```
<console>:36: error: not found: value z
       z.show(df)
```

Upon further inspection, I've found that Zeppelin Context is not being recognized; when I try to manually import SparkZeppelinContext, I get the following error:

```
error: object zeppelin is not a member of package org.apache
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this error? Here are additional details about my environment:

- Windows 10
- Java/JDK 8
- Spark 2.4.6
- Zeppelin 0.8.2

Comment: DId you happen to come to a solution to fix this ?